# How can I transfer highscore in other scene - iOS8 [SWIFT]

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I'm making a game with three scenes.

1. PresentationScene
2. GameScene
3. GameOverScene

In GameScene I have all my game. I can display Highscore in this scene with this code :

```
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")



    if(balloonDestroyed > highscore)
    {
        defaults.setInteger(balloonDestroyed, forKey: "highscore")

    }

    var highscoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    var highscoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

    highscoreLabel.text = "highscore : \(highscoreShow)"
    highscoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(200, 200)


    addChild(highscoreLabel)
```

My first problem is when balloonDestroyed > highscore, the highscoreLabel doesn't update 
the second problem is : how can i transfer this highscore to the PresentScene and GameOverScene

Someone can help me?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use highscore outside of GameScene, you need to make it global. You can do that by creating a new class and defining it there, or just defining it outside of the GameScene brackets. If these two lines:

var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

are inside a set of these: {}, it's not global and your use is restricted.

Comment: Great! I'm pretty new to this as well, so I'm happy to help when I can.

Answer (score 0):

thank you ClareHuxtable !!

For other new programer like me I post my code here to transfer a Highscore to other scenes :

So I initialize global variables in my GameViewController (before the first "{" ) with this code :

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
```

In my GameScene :

```
if(score > highscore)
{
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")

}
```

and In the new scene where I want display the highscore :

```
var highscoreShow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
var highscoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

    highscoreLabel.text = "highscore : \(highscoreShow)"
    highscoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    highscoreLabel.fontName = "Chalkduster"
    highscoreLabel.fontSize = 15
    highscoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Right
    highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width - 10, 10)

    addChild(highscoreLabel)
```

I hope that will help someone else :-)